# Valid signing identity not found. while run the application in device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS development. I was installing the application in iPhone 4s for testing. While I run the app through XCode with iPhone connected to the MAC mini. In the issues navigator I saw the following error:

> Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: ()' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains.

When open the XCode organizer-> Device tab all the provisioning profile in that has the same status as **Valid signing identity not found**.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please install development certificate in your keychain

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the `development certificate(.p12)` associated to your current provisioning profile.

Get it exported from the system keychain access, where it was originally created.